# Function not assigning values in Racket

Tags: racket

Why following function (match-redefine) is not working?

```
(define vlist (list 10 20 30))
(match-define (list aa bb cc) (list 1 2 3))
(define alist (list aa bb cc))
alist
vlist

(define (match-redefine dst_list src_list) 
  (for ((d dst_list)(s src_list)) (set! d s))    )

(rnmatch-redefine alist vlist)
alist
vlist
```

The output is:

```
'(1 2 3)
'(10 20 30)
'(1 2 3)
'(10 20 30)
```

The destination list (alist) remains unchanged. Can this function be made to work?

Edit: I tried vector as suggested by @OscarLopez in the answers, but it does not work:

```
(match-define (list a b c)  (list 0 0 0 )  )
(define variable_vect (vector a b c))
a
b
c

(define valuelist (list 1 2 3) )  
(for ((i variable_vect)(j valuelist))   ; does not work 
   (set! i j))
variable_vect
a
b
c

(set! variable_vect valuelist)
(println "------- after ----------")
variable_vect
a
b
c
```

Output is:

```
0
0
0
'#(0 0 0)
0
0
0
"------- after ----------"
'(1 2 3)
0
0
0
```

Edit: It seems I will have to use special class to apply this:

```
(define myob%
  (class object%
    (super-new)
    (init-field val)
    (define/public (getval) val)
    (define/public (setval v) (set! val v))   ))

(define (copyvalues objlist valuelist)
  (for ((a alist)(v valuelist)) (send a setval v))  )

(define (show_objlist alist)
  (for ((a alist))  (println (send a getval)))  )

; USED AS FOLLOWS: 

(define ob1 (make-object myob% 5))
(define ob2 (make-object myob% 5))
(define ob3 (make-object myob% 5))
(define alist (list ob1 ob2 ob3))

(println "---------- first assignment -----------")
(define vlist (list 1 2 3))
(copyvalues alist vlist)
(show_objlist alist)

(println "---------- second assignment -----------")
(define ylist (list 10 20 30))
(copyvalues alist ylist)
(show_objlist alist)

(println "---------- individual access -----------")
(send ob1 getval)
(send ob3 getval)
```

Output is:

```
"---------- first assignment -----------"
1
2
3
"---------- second assignment -----------"
10
20
30
"---------- individual access -----------"
10
30
```

Comment: You're only modifying the local variable `d`, and I believe Racket's pairs are immmutable anyway.

Comment: Any special keyword or function to make them mutable?

Comment: You can always change language to one of the Schemes, or work with [mutable pairs](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/mpairs.html). But mutation in itself is pretty un-Schemey and very un-Rackety, and mutating parameters even more so.

Comment: Or you could switch to a programming language that encourages mutation and imperative programming, so far you're trying to use Scheme as something else.

Comment: When you go through a list or a vector with `(for ([x ...]) ...)`, the `x` is a (local variable pointing to a) *value*, not a *reference*. So `set!` can replace that value with another value, but it was never a reference into the original list or vector

Comment: I recommend reading [Objects and Imperative Update](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/eval-model.html#%28part._.Objects_and_.Imperative_.Update%29) in the Racket documentation. It does a good job of explaining how mutation and references work in Racket. It uses slightly different terminology than you might be used to, so read it carefully and make sure you understand how it defines terms like *value* and *object*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, this is not the way we do things in Scheme. Besides, your code is simply reassigning a local variable that was pointing to an element in the list, the destination list remains unmodified.

You could use vectors instead of lists - those *can* be modified, exactly as you would modify an array in the most common programming languages, something like this:

```
(define value_list (list   1 2 3))
(define value_vect (vector 0 0 0))

value_vect
=> '#(0 0 0)

(for [(i (in-range (vector-length value_vect)))
      (value value_list)]
  (vector-set! value_vect i value))

value_vect
=> '#(1 2 3)
```

Anyway you should not modify a list of variables, just return a list with the new values. And don't think about mutating the list - although it *is* possible to do so using mutable pairs, that's not the correct way to deal with this situation, please stop thinking about mutating everything you encounter!

Comment: Vector is also not working. Please see edit in my question.

Comment: @rnso it won't work because, as I said, _you're just reassigning a local variable_, not the content of the vector - for that you need to specify the index that you want to modify. See my update.

Comment: Can variable names a, b and c be kept in the vector to be used separately also?

Comment: No, that's not how variables work in any programming language.

Answer (score 2):

You ask why the function is not working.
The reason is that `(set! d s)` is doing something
you do not expect.

Observe:

```
#lang racket
(define vlist (list 10 20 30))
(match-define (list aa bb cc) (list 1 2 3))
(define alist (list aa bb cc))
alist
vlist

(define (match-redefine dst_list src_list) 
  (for ((d dst_list)(s src_list))
    (set! d s)
    (displayln (~a "d is now: " s))))

(match-redefine alist vlist)
```

The output is:

```
'(1 2 3)
'(10 20 30)
d is now: 10
d is now: 20
d is now: 30
```

This means that you change the value of `d` (not the value of the variable which corresponds to the symbols that `d` runs through.

See your previous question on the same topic.